# Logstash file input not reparsing file

Tags: logstash

I have the following problem, I need logstash to reparse already parsed files:

Scenario that doesn't work but should:

- upload file to watched folder
- logstash processes it, saves to elastic, removes it (file_completed_action => "log_and_delete"), great
- I upload the same file again, same name, same content.
- logstash doesnt do anything, I want it to process it again

  Here is my file input config:

```
file {
          mode => "read"
          exclude => "*.tif"
          path => ["/home/xmls/*.xml"]
          file_completed_action => "log_and_delete"
          file_completed_log_path => "/var/log/logstash/completed.log"
          sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
          start_position => "beginning"
          codec => multiline {
                  pattern => ".*"
                  what => "previous"
                  max_lines => 100000
                  max_bytes => "200 MiB"
          }
          type => "my-custom-type-1"
}
```

`sincedb_path` is set to /dev/null, it should not remember processed files, also tried setting `ignore_older` to 0, didn't help.

Also tried messing with queue settings in logstash.yml, changed it to persistent, didn't work ...

I'm using logstash version 7.5, logstash-input-file (4.1.11), running in linux machine.

When I restart logstash, then the unprocessed files get processed and cleaned up.
I need it to work without restarting.